# separate string with reg ex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

When I try to separate this string:

```
<b>Pristatymo laikas: </b>08-17h (visoje Lietuvoje)<br /><b>Dovanų kuponai:</b> <br />Panaudotas 200.00 Lt. dovanų kuponas, kurio kodas: xxxxx<br /><b>Mokėtina suma:</b> 12.00 Lt. <br />
```

with reg ex pattern:

```
<b>(.*)</b>
```

I get this match:

```
<b>Pristatymo laikas: </b>08-17h (visoje Lietuvoje)<br /><b>Dovanų kuponai:</b> <br />Panaudotas 200.00 Lt. dovanų kuponas, kurio kodas: xxxxx<br /><b>Mokėtina suma:</b>
```

But I what get all words in `<b>` tag separated like:

```
<b>Pristatymo laikas: </b>
<b>Dovanų kuponai:</b>
<b>Mokėtina suma:</b>
```

How to write correct pattern?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that `*` is by default greedy. It will eat `</b>` as well as long as there is still another `</b>` in order to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*?` instead:

```
<b>(.*?)</b>
```

The `?` quantifier (non-greedy) matches as little as possible and thus stops at the first encounter of `</b>`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/nE1wE1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow `.*` with `?` for a [non-greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) match.

```
<b>(.*?)</b>
```

Although you can do this with a simple regular expression, it is better to use a Parser for this.

```
$html = '<b>Pristatymo laikas: </b>08-17h (visoje Lietuvoje)<br />
<b>Dovanų kuponai:</b> <br />Panaudotas 200.00 Lt. dovanų kuponas, kurio kodas:
xxxxx<br /><b>Mokėtina suma:</b> 12.00 Lt. <br />';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//b') as $tag) {
   echo $tag->ownerDocument->saveHTML($tag) . "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
<b>Pristatymo laikas: </b>
<b>DovanÅ³ kuponai:</b>
<b>MokÄtina suma:</b>
```